# Getting an error on field module when saving a node

Tags: nodes, entities

When I'm saving a node using `node_save`, I'm getting the following fatal error:

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /data/www/www.example.com/htdocs/modules/field/field.attach.inc on line 664

This is not happening every time `node_save` is called, only for a certain new node and I can't find anything strange about the fields I'm populating. Any clue?

Comment: Try to install xhprof and check why node_save works so long

Answer (score 0):

I would check cck fields to find which one causes the issue first and go from there, the error message related to 'fetch entities from cache, if applicable'.